# Can't scroll to the top or bottom

Tags: html, css

I just created three simple cards using HTML and CSS. Used media query and when the specified width is reached I am unable to see the top card and bottom card fully, only can scroll up to a certain point in the page. Here's my HTML and CSS code‎‏‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎

```css
:root {
  --clr-primary-300: hsl(31, 77%, 52%);
  --clr-primary-400: hsl(184, 100%, 22%);
  --clr-primary-500: hsl(179, 100%, 13%);
}

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 95%);
}

h1 {
  color: hsl(0, 0%, 95%);
  font-family: 'Big Shoulders Display', cursive;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

p {
  font-family: 'Lexend Deca', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.75);
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  height: 126px;
}

.card {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: flex;
}

.cols {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 40px;
}

.i {
  background-color: var(--clr-primary-300);
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}

.ii {
  background-color: var(--clr-primary-400);
}

.iii {
  background-color: var(--clr-primary-500);
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
}

button {
  font-family: 'Lexend Deca', sans-serif;
  width: 130px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.i button {
  color: var(--clr-primary-300);
}

.ii button {
  color: var(--clr-primary-400);
}

.iii button {
  color: var(--clr-primary-500);
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 375px) {
  .card {
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 90%;
  }
  .i {
    border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
  }
  .iii {
    border-radius: 0 0 6px 6px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="cols i">
    <img src="images/icon-sedans.svg" alt="sedans">
    <h1>Sedans</h1>
    <p>Choose a sedan for its affordability and excellent fuel economy. Ideal for cruising in the city or on your next road trip.</p>
    <button>Learn More</button>
  </div>
  <div class="cols ii">
    <img src="images/icon-suvs.svg" alt="suvs">
    <h1>SUVs</h1>
    <p>Take an SUV for its spacious interior, power, and versatility. Perfect for your next family vacation and off-road adventures.</p>
    <button>Learn More</button>
  </div>
  <div class="cols iii">
    <img src="images/icon-luxury.svg" alt="luxury">
    <h1>Luxury</h1>
    <p>Cruise in the best car brands without the bloated prices. Enjoy the enhanced comfort of a luxury rental and arrive in style.</p>
    <button>Learn More</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You've centered the card `horizontally` and `vertically` using `transform` when the `position: absolute`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are trying to center the content vertically and horizontally, try using flex for this.

Replace Your .card with below css

```
   .card {
        max-width: 600px;
        margin: 20px auto;
        width: 100%;
        min-height: 100vh;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        display: flex;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks now I am able to see all the cards perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following css in media query to make it position `relative`

```
.card {
        position: relative !important;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        transform: none;
        flex-direction: column;
        padding: 1.5rem;
    }
```

```css
:root {
    --clr-primary-300: hsl(31, 77%, 52%);
    --clr-primary-400: hsl(184, 100%, 22%);
    --clr-primary-500: hsl(179, 100%, 13%);
}

* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 95%);
}

h1 {
    color: hsl(0, 0%, 95%);
    font-family: 'Big Shoulders Display', cursive;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

p {
    font-family: 'Lexend Deca', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.75);
    line-height: 1.5;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    height: 126px;
}

.card {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    display: flex;
}

.cols {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 40px;
}

.i {
    background-color: var(--clr-primary-300);
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}

.ii {
    background-color: var(--clr-primary-400);
}

.iii {
    background-color: var(--clr-primary-500);
    border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
}

button {
    font-family: 'Lexend Deca', sans-serif;
    width: 130px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 30px;
}

.i button {
    color: var(--clr-primary-300);
}

.ii button {
    color: var(--clr-primary-400);
}

.iii button {
    color: var(--clr-primary-500);
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 375px) {
    .card {
        position: relative !important;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        transform: none;
        flex-direction: column;
        padding: 1.5rem;
    }
    .i {
        border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
    }
    .iii {
        border-radius: 0 0 6px 6px;
    }
}
```

```html
    <div class="card">
        <div class="cols i">
            <img src="images/icon-sedans.svg" alt="sedans">
            <h1>Sedans</h1>
            <p>Choose a sedan for its affordability and excellent fuel economy. Ideal for cruising in the city or on your next road trip.</p>
            <button>Learn More</button>
        </div>
        <div class="cols ii">
            <img src="images/icon-suvs.svg" alt="suvs">
            <h1>SUVs</h1>
            <p>Take an SUV for its spacious interior, power, and versatility. Perfect for your next family vacation and off-road adventures.</p>
            <button>Learn More</button>
        </div>
        <div class="cols iii">
            <img src="images/icon-luxury.svg" alt="luxury">
            <h1>Luxury</h1>
            <p>Cruise in the best car brands without the bloated prices. Enjoy the enhanced comfort of a luxury rental and arrive in style.</p>
            <button>Learn More</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```